# Microsoft Teams conversations in SharePoint Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams, yammer

Can we display Microsoft Teams conversations into SharePoint pages just like Yammer feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not available from Microsoft yet. Not even added to their Roadmap site. However, you can vote for the user voice listing [requesting this feature](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/33746158-conversation-webpart-for-sharepoint) to bump up the count.